# How do I managed to Download and Convert an Image to Base64 Data Url?

Tags: javascript, blob, converters, tobase64string

My task was to crop an image and upload to amazon s3 with various sizes. But the plugin I have used to crop provides Blob url instead if Base 64 string I have tried several methods to convert the blob url to base64 string but I was end up with this error `javasdcript TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.` Then I realised that firstly I have to download the image from blob url then only it will be available to convert.

Function

```js
const getBase64ImageFromUrl =  async(imageUrl) => {
  var res = await fetch(imageUrl);
  var blob = await res.blob();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var reader  = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        resolve(reader.result);
    }, false);

    reader.onerror = () => {
      return reject(this);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  })
}
```

Usage

```js
const blobUrl = "blob:http://localhost:8000/0bea79ee-878f-49a1-9256-9f1f0be73723"
const base64String = await getBase64ImageFromUrl(blobUrl)
console.log(base64String)
```

Comment: So what is the problem..? I tested it and it seems to work.

Comment: @i.brod It is just a post to share the knowledge.